# How do I get Ubuntu to detect my Intel Graphics?

Tags: intel-graphics

I have a system with Nvidia graphics card.

Doing the following

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

only shows my Nvidia card. How can I get it to detect the Intel one as well?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output shows something like this :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: yes..it shows all that. Now, I'd like to make my system actually use the Intel card. The issue is that I need to access the Intel GPU memory via OpenCL, and the drivers happen to be using X11, which absolutely requires your display to be driven by it.